# Qemu - Redirect host input to guest UART for bare metal kernel

Tags: serial-port, arm, qemu, uart, bare-metal

I'm writing a kernel from scratch in Rust for 64-bit ARM devices. For testing purpose, I use Qemu `virt` machine.

Currently, I'm able to write characters from guest to host console through UART. Now I would like to do the opposite, i.e. send characters from host console to guest UART port. Is there a way to do this? Should I add some arguments to Qemu?

I run Qemu `virt` machine with the following arguments:

```
qemu-system-aarch64 -M virt -cpu cortex-a57 -nographic -serial pty -S -kernel target/aarch64-unknown-none/debug/cortex-a57
```

It gives me a new pty that I can attach with `screen /dev/pts/mypty`. Then I run the program tapping `c` in Qemu console. 
I would like to use the same pty (or a new one?) to write data to the guest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

QEMU always redirects both input and output for a guest UART to the same place; this is true of all of '-serial stdio', '-nographic' (which does an implicit '-serial mon:stdio') and '-serial pty'. So you don't need to do anything extra. If UART input is not working then the problem seems likely to be a bug in your guest code.

Answer (score 2):

Just read the same TTY as Qemu redirects all input to the same place.